# Return pointer to the node of the linked list from the function

Tags: c, pointers, return-value

I try to pass the pointer to the linked list node from the function.
Here the pseudo code (I'm using C):

```
node_t *node = % first node initialization % ; //global

int func(int valueToFind, node_t *parentNode) {
    while(node = node->next()) {
        if(node->value == valueToFind) {
            parentNode = node->prev();
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    node_t *parent;
    EDIT:
       parent = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    END EDIT
    if(1==func(16, parent)) {//searching for value 16
        printf("%d\n", parent->value);
    }
}
```

At the line where `printf("%d\n", parent->value);` the program is crashing.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's `node->prev()`? Is it a function call? Please post MCVE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [correct way to change values of c pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382065/correct-way-to-change-values-of-c-pointers)

Comment: @EugeneSh. because this is originally a C++ question before the edit.

Comment: This is invalid in C. Unless it has some function fields.

Comment: It's not duplicate to the "correct way to change values of c pointers".
With simple data types and string I don't have a problem :(

Comment: Is this really C or C++? Please tag only the one you are writing/compiling (the modern languages have many differences!)

Comment: @Michael It sure is a duplicate. Did you read the accepted answer? `parentNode = …` *inside* `func` won't change `parent` in `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `parentNode` of `func()` is passed by value, that means even if you changed its value inside the function, it has nothing to do with the outside variable in `main()`. So when `printf("%d\n", parent->value);` is called, `parent` is still an invalid pointer.

You might try *passed by pointer* (i.e. pointer of pointer) to accomplish it. Such as:

```
int func(int valueToFind, node_t **parentNode) {
//                               ~~
    while(node = node->next()) {
        if(node->value == valueToFind) {
            *parentNode = node->prev();
//          ~
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
if(1==func(16, &parent)) {//searching for value 16
//             ~
    printf("%d\n", parent->value);
}
```

Comment: @Michael I've added some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, in your `main()` function, `node_t *parent;` is local to `main()` and you did not allocate any valid memory to it.

That said, in the call, `func(16, parent)` you have passed the `parent` using pass by value, so even if the function is intended to make any change to `parent`, it will not *reflect back* to `main()`.

So,

```
 printf("%d\n", parent->value);
```

is invalid memory access and  invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it. The question is edited.

Comment: @Michael Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
parentNode = node->prev();
```

This pointer variable is local to func().
If you want to keep it, you have to return the pointer value stored in it.

After func() returns, the local parentNode is gone.

What you passed to func() was just a copy of the pointer stored in parent variable.

See this solution:

```
node_t *node = % first node initialization % ; //global

node_t* func(int valueToFind) {
    while(node = node->next()) {
        if(node->value == valueToFind) {
            return node->prev();
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    node_t *parent = func(16);
    if(parent) {//searching for value 16
        printf("%d\n", parent->value);
    }
}
```

Now parent is really holding a pointer, or a 'memory address'.
And parent has a *true* value, which is, different of 0. Every value different of 0 is true in C. If it's NULL (or 0), it's *false*.

Comment: Notice the function return type....

Comment: Sorry, you're mixing data types. I need to pass the parent node to the parameter passed by reference.

Comment: @Michael There's no reference in c.

Comment: Pointer can be called by reference, because you pass the address and not value

Comment: Thanks, @Sourav Ghosh. Fixed it.

Comment: @Michael In your case you're passing a pointer, so you need to use *pointer of pointer*.

Comment: Michael, there's a difference between dereferencing a variable inside a function and actually assigning a pointer to a local variable. That's a common problem in C when someone starts learning pointers. Remember that when you do local_var = pointer_value, that local var will be gone. You did not pass a variable into the function, just it's copied value.